# How to be UX Researcher supporting an open source project with differing user objectives?

Tags: process, open-source

I've seen other questions about user testing or contributing UI to open source projects- I'm curious if anyone has done UX Research *for* open source tools. I'd like to get better embedded in their github processes and help them engage with community beyond the biased group of devs building the thing.

A few pieces of context:

1. I am a FTE on a team that is partnering with an open source project- so the company employs FTE engineers and PM on the open source tool but there is also a big community of developers. As a researcher, I've been deterred from engaging in the ways I would on a normal team, mainly because the open source contribution process is so distributed and doesnt allow for roadmapping/UXR engagement.
2. I did an original set of heuristics evaluation and "missing essential features" workshops with the team, but was told to put a pin in the work until we hired a PM (which happened recently).
3. At its core, i feel the open source team believes we should be focusing more on the expert user (aka them) rather than the beginner, no code user (which is the company's objective), so i find my feedback and strategy to be at odds with them.

Any resources would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the question can be answered in a more generalized form as "**How to get the UX role into an existing process?**"

Changing a process can start from the management level if they change the meeting structure (meetings between devs and UX) or if UX becomes a quality gate for releasing features. Then they have to talk to you.

Otherwise, you have to think about how to integrate yourself into their process. I would start with helping them out. **Ask if they need help with screen design, icons etc.** Slowly, they will know what you are doing and ask you for help more often and also realize the value of having UX in the development process.